# How can I copy a remote image over HTTP to gtk.gdk.pixbuf by Python?

Tags: python, gtk, pynotify

this is first post here and I am a noob programmer.
This may be a stupid question.

I'd like to create a personal Twitter notifier on GNOE Desktop. And I've decided to use `pynotify` and `Tweepy`.
Now I just want to make `pynotify` show Twitter user's icon, and there seems to be 2 ways using `pynotify`; setting URI to local image file, or using `pixbuf` API. I suppose downloading the icon and setting URI to the local icon by `urllib` is easier though don't want to make local cache file. Is it possible to pass directly a remote image to `pixbuf`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you mean something [like this](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq08.016.htp)?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want. Thank you, mg.
Additionally, I had to search this FAQ by myself. Sorry for bothering.